# How to know the time/date of when the packages are installed?

Tags: command-line

I installed and removed so many packages on my system.But it don't know when it was installed and when it was removed.

I want to know when the packages are installed on my PC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd improve on things simply with:

```
$ zgrep -sh ' install iperf' /var/log/dpkg*
2013-02-21 14:07:46 install iperf:amd64 <none> 2.0.5-3
```

`zgrep` doesn't care if you hand it uncompressed data so it's just easiest to use that. Obviously if you need *every* install you could remove `iperf` and see everything, but it seems more logical to search down on that at the same time.